# Entity Framewrok 5 fluent mapping for many to many with 3 entities

Tags: many-to-many, entity-framework-5

I have the following scenario that is giving me a hard time:

```
public class SegUser
{
      public string IdUser { get; set; }

      public List<SegRol> SegRoles { get; set; }

      public virtual List<SegApps> Apps{ get; set; }
}

public class SegRole
{
     public virtual int IdRole { get; set; }

     public virtual List<SegUer> SegUsers { get; set; }

    public virtual List<SegApp> Apps { get; set; }

}

public class SegApp
{
      public virtual int IdApp{ get; set; }

      public virtual List<SegUser> Users { get; set; }

      public virtual List<SegRole> Roles { get; set; }

}
```

In my database I have those 3 tables and an extra table with 3 PKs (one for each entity) to establish the relationship between those 3 entities.

How can I achieve the mapping with Entity Framework 5 fluent API.

I've already tried:

```
    private void MapSegUser()
    {
        //mapping of another fields

        entityConfiguration
            .HasMany(x => x.SegRoles)
            .WithMany(x => x.SegUsers)
            .Map(mc =>
            {
                mc.MapLeftKey("id_role");
                mc.MapRightKey("id_user");
                mc.ToTable("seg_users_roles");
            });

        entityConfiguration
            .HasMany(x => x.Apps)
            .WithMany(x => x.Users)
            .Map(mc =>
            {
                mc.MapLeftKey("id_app");
                mc.MapRightKey("id_user");
                mc.ToTable("seg_users_roles_apps");
            });

    }


   private void MapSegApp()
    {
        //mapping of another fields

          entityConfiguration
            .HasMany(x => x.Users)
            .WithMany(x => x.Apps)
            .Map(mc =>
            {
                mc.MapLeftKey("id_user");
                mc.MapRightKey("id_app");
                mc.ToTable("seg_users_roles_apps");
            });

    }


     private void MapSegRole()
    {
        //mapping of another fields

        entityConfiguration
            .HasMany(x => x.SegUsers)
            .WithMany(x => x.SegRoles)
            .Map(mc =>
            {
                mc.MapLeftKey("id_user");
                mc.MapRightKey("id_role");
                mc.ToTable("seg_users_roles");
            });
    }
```

Comment: You can only do this by mapping the junction table to a class and having three one-to-many associations to it. Each bilateral many-to-many association is meaningless.

Comment: Yes! that's a good idea It works for me. Thanks!